# Only allow 7 alphanumeric characters, but unlimited spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input box.

I want to allow 0-7 alphanumeric characters, and spaces, but no limit on the amount of spaces.

So it could have...

```
ABC1234
```

Or..

```
AB C    1 234
```

But nothing else.

Thanks!

Comment: Please share what you have tried. BTW, why not remove whitespace from the string first?

Comment: Thank you for letting us know, Tribe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to match "alphanumeric character followed by optional spaces" at most 7 times:

```
^\s*(?:\w\s*){0,7}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/NarIL8/1

Comment: Nope, between 0-7 characters is what I'm after. This seems to be the solution.

Comment: @tribe: So, you want to allow strings like `___          _`?